# Github Action pull request doesn't provide last commit by github_sha

Tags: git, github, github-actions

I have a github action workflow which is triggered on pull requests. I want to find the files that have been changed in each commit so I'm trying to run `git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r ${{ github.sha }}`
However it doesn't return the hash commit of the latest commit in that pull request. I get returned back another hash commit (which I can't find its commit anywhere in my repo).
Anyone know how to fix this or another way I could find all the files that changed in a commit in a pull request?

Edit -- yml file

```
name: test
on: [pull_request]
jobs:
  build: 
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - checkout my repo
    - install python
    - run a python script
      run: |
        CHANGED_FILES=$(git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r ${{ github.sha }})
        python3 .github/scripts/test.py $CHANGED_FILES
```

My hash commit generated by github.sha (here ^) doens't seem to match the actual hash of my commit.

Comment: Does it actually work to use an expression in the script like `${{ github.sha }}` Did you try printing this value to see if it actually contains anything. Try comparing that to the `GITHUB_SHA` environment variable.

Comment: It does seem to work, it does print a value. And when I change the trigger to push it works perfectly, matching to the actual commit hash. The problem arises when the trigger changes to pull request, the commit hashes don't match and then I don't get returned any files

Comment: Try using the `GITHUB_REF` environment variable. So `git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r $GITHUB_REF`

Comment: Getting this error `fatal: ambiguous argument 'refs/pull/num/merge': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.`

Comment: I found another way around it. I'm using this action from the github marketplace `Changed Files Exporter`. Seems to be working so far

Comment: When trying to find the SHA related to the PR I found `${{ github.event.pull_request.head.sha  }}`; i.e. this is useful if you have multiple actions driven by different events on the same PR (e.g. your `opened` event drives your CI, then `labeled` events drive CD).

Answer (score 27):

I've bumped into a similar problem with a different trigger. Turns out, you can print the GitHub variables using the following step:

```
- name: Dump GitHub context
  env:
    GITHUB_CONTEXT: ${{ toJson(github) }}
  run: echo "$GITHUB_CONTEXT"
```

In the case of `pull_request` the hash of the latest commit can be found in the `${{ github.event.pull_request.head.sha }}` variable, whereas `${{ github.sha }}` refers to the PR merge commit.

Comment: The full event payload can be found on GitHub Developer's Guide: https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#pullrequestevent

Comment: This is awesome, man!! GitHub should highlight it in official document.

Comment: So if you have a PR and continue to push to it, you can read out the last commit files from ```github.event.pull_request.head.sha``` (with git diff-tree) but when the PR is closed and merged you need to compare with ```${{ github.sha }}``` to list files?